# XJC throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException after migrating JAXB from javax to jakarta

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, jakarta-migration

What I'm trying to achieve

- Move Spring application (not Spring boot) from Java 8 to 17 and Tomcat 8 to 10.

Issues

- After following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception) I have replaced javax libraries(mostly for xml binding) with jakarta but we have a gradle script that uses **xjc** and is failing with the following exception and couldn't find how to fix it.

  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

```
xjc(removeOldOutput:"yes", target: sourcesDir, binding: ${"schema"}/processPaymentBindings.jaxb{ 
     schema(dir: schema, includes:"provider/gpos/processPayment/*.xsd)
    arg(value: "-Xdefault-value"
    arg(value: "-extension")
    produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java Do")
}
```

We use the following JAXB dependencies for tasks on Gradle for your reference:

- jaxb: jakarta activation
- jaxb: xmlbind
- jaxb: impl
- jaxb1: impl
- jaxb: xjc
- jaxb2: common

Comment: "we have a gradle script that uses xjc and is failing" is not detailed enough so that anyonw knows whats going on.

Comment: i added the code. Please re open.

Comment: @BalusC Can you please re open the question ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], which includes the relevant Gradle plugins and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the following dependencies which used to be included in the standard JRE but are now third party jars

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does that version of xjc generate source code with the jakarta classes?

Comment: Those are the wrong versions if the OP migrated to the jakarta versions.